# Is it possible to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the functions $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R} $ and $g: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R} $ , with $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Also consider that there is a sequence $(g_n) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $g_n \to g$ a.e. and there is a function $h \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $|g_n(x)| \leqslant h(x)$ a.e. I want to show that

$$\int_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)}|f(x)g_n(x)|dx \to \int_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)}|f(x)g(x)|dx.$$

But, nothing is known about the integrability of $f$. Is it possible to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence Theorem?

Comment: $f$ probably does need more conditions. Is $f$ in $L^\infty$ for example

Comment: Given $f g_n$'s are integrable, have you tried using DCT? It does look promising

Comment: As $|g_n(x)| \leqslant h(x)$ a.e, then $f(x)|g_n(x)| \leqslant f(x)h(x)$ a.e. In this case, I think I would need the integrability of the product function $f(x)h(x)$, but I don't have that information.

Comment: Why do you think the result would hold in full generality?

Comment: To construct a counterexample: take $g\in L^1$, $f\not\in L^\infty$ such that $fg$ is not integrable.

Comment: The question, as stated now, does not assume anything about $f$. So $f$ could even be a non-measurable function.